# BouncyCastle.dll using DH in C# error?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

```
var dhparams = new DHParameters(
                new BigInteger("E7A69EBDF105F2A6BBDEAD7E798F76A209AD73FB466431E2E7352ED262F8C558F10BEFEA977DE9E21DCEE9B04D245F300ECCBBA03E72630556D011023F9E857F"),
                new BigInteger("05"));
var genparams = new DHKeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), dhparams);
var generator = new DHKeyPairGenerator();
generator.Init(genparams);
var pair = generator.GenerateKeyPair();
var pubkey = (DHPublicKeyParameters)pair.Public;
//so public key pubkey.Y
```

am geting error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   `stack in`var dhparams = new DHParameters(....`

I don't know what's wrong it's my 1st time though , also pubkey.Y is the public key right? thanks

Comment: It looks like you got your answer in [An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370861/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-formatexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll) so I'm voting to close this one.

Answer (score 0):

Same as:

[An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370861/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-formatexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll)