# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, string, biginteger, bouncycastle

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
    string p = "E7A69EBDF105F2A6BBDEAD7E798F76A209AD73FB466431E2E7352ED262F8C558F10BEFEA977DE9E21DCEE9B04D245F300ECCBBA03E72630556D011023F9E857F";
    BigInteger P= new BigInteger(p);
```

throwing Exception

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffe
r& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo in
fo)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger..ctor(String str, Int32 radix)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger..ctor(String value)
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: Consider changing the title of this question - the exception is being thrown by the Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger class, not mscorlib.dll

Comment: Are you targetting .net 4.0 because then you probably should use System.Numerics.BigInteger instead if possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: @DaveRead the dubgger is breaking and giving me the Title Error but the expection throw that expection.

Comment: Are you using this implementation of BigInteger? http://biginteger.codeplex.com/releases/view/16762

Comment: @Stormenet yeah i do but i cant find System.Numerics it's not there

Comment: Did you add reference to System.Numerics.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your number string is in hexadecimal, you'll need to specify the radix in the constructor as:

```
BigInteger P = new BigInteger(p,16);
```